# What causes these extra spaces in front of the package menu header?

Tags: package, header-line

[image: package-menu]

I want to get rid of these extra spaces that is in the left.

I have tried the following after reading a bit on propertize:

```el
(setq-local header-line-format
            (propertize header-line-format 'display '((space :align-to 0))))
```

Comment: Those spaces are there because when you mark a package, that is where it displays the character code for the selected action. "Getting rid of these spaces" doesn't make much sense to me if you don't also address the thing they're used for.

Comment: Right, forgot things could be done interactively in there as well. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2-space padding is hard implemented as

`(setq tabulated-list-padding 2)`

in `package-menu-mode`.
The documentation string of `tabulated-list-padding` says:

> Documentation:
>   Number of characters preceding each Tabulated List mode entry.
>   By default, lines are padded with spaces, but you can use the
>   function `tabulated-list-put-tag' to change this.

The end of `package-menu-mode` reads:

```el
  ...
  (setq tabulated-list-padding 2)
  (setq tabulated-list-sort-key (cons "Status" nil))
  (add-hook 'tabulated-list-revert-hook 'package-menu--refresh nil t)
  (tabulated-list-init-header))
```

There is no customization option and no hook to change `tabulated-list-padding` between the `(setq tabulated-list-padding 2)` and `(tabulated-list-init-header)`.

This makes the modification of `tabulated-list-padding` in `package-menu-mode` a bit hard.

[Phils comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22642/what-causes-these-extra-spaces-in-front-of-the-package-menu-header/22643?noredirect=1#comment35199_22642) points out that customization of the padding makes little sense since those two one-character columns are used for marking packages.

If you really want to modify it and you do not like to overwrite `package-menu-mode` completely you need the following advices:

```el
(defun package-menu-header-advice (&rest args)
  (setq tabulated-list-padding 0))

(defun package-header-avoid-padding (old-function &rest args)
  "Avoid padding in `package-menu-mode'."
  (unwind-protect
      (progn
    (advice-add 'tabulated-list-init-header :before #'package-menu-header-advice)
    (apply old-function args))
    (advice-remove 'tabulated-list-init-header #'package-menu-header-advice)))

(advice-add 'package-menu-mode :around #'package-header-avoid-padding)
```

Comment: Why don't you just `let`-binding `tabulated-list-padding` around `(apply old-function args)`?

Comment: @lunaryorn The edit should make this clear. The `setq` in `package-menu-mode` overrides any `let`-binding. `setq` is fine in `package-menu-header-advice` since `tabulated-list-padding` is buffer-local.

Comment: @Tobias Will mark as resolved, cause, well it works even though the end goal is pretty stupid (see [phils' comment](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22642/what-causes-these-extra-spaces-in-front-of-the-package-menu-header/22643#comment35199_22642)).

Comment: @MathieuMarques Yes, I see. Maybe, that is the reason why `(setq tabulated-list-padding 2)` is hard-coded. Good catch from Phils. I will add a remark in the answer. But, also good that you marked this as the resolution. Because, the answer shows some background about the padding of the tabulated list.